# OpenVPN Adding Client Keys

Tags: openvpn

I have OpenVPN set up and working fine, however I want to add a new client key to it. Going off of the documentation, I issued the following commands with the following output on a CentOS box.

```
$ cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa
$ source ./vars
NOTE: If you run ./clean-all, I will be doing a rm -rf on /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys
$ ./pkitool client-new
Please edit the vars script to reflect your configuration,
then source it with "source ./vars".
Next, to start with a fresh PKI configuration and to delete any
previous certificates and keys, run "./clean-all".
Finally, you can run this tool (pkitool) to build certificates/keys.
```

It also says the same thing if I try the command `./build-key client-new`. Any idea on why I can't do that? I need to keep all of my other keys, I just need one more. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

try

> . ./vars

that loads the variables that are in the vars file.

I don't know why, if someone could explain why. I thought ./vars would just run all commands in the script, including the exports, so they would be in your env. Anywhay, putting an extra .  in front of the command works for me.

Comment: I tried doing that as well and I get the same output.

Comment: actually you may need to load the vars via `source ../vars` :)

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with a fresh install of easy-rsa from the ubuntu (16.04) repository.

For me, the solution was to create the `keys` directory. I also needed to create `index.txt` and initialize `serial`.

So after

`source ./vars`

The KEY_DIR environment variable specifies a directory that needs to exist, which I had to create and initialize.

`mkdir -p $KEY_DIR`

`touch $KEY_DIR/index.txt`

`echo '1' > $KEY_DIR/serial`

Answer (score 0):

if you have a certificate file you can use PuttyGen.exe to load it and export the public and private keys separately.  That might help you?

Some instructions here to use PuttyGen.exe , if you can click this link: http://www.newartisans.com/2007/09/how-to-administer-openvpn.html

Answer (score 0):

I changed some directory information in the vars file and that ended up fixing the problem. It was using pwd as the directory for EASY_RSA and if you were in the wrong directory it had some weird issues. Once that problem was fixed I received another error that was easily fixed. I had the ca.key encrypted for security purposes and it was complaining about not being able to read that but that was a simple decrypt fix. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using OpenVPN 2.x you might check whether you are making changes in the correct directory, possibly you may need to be working in:

> /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0

I don't know how CentOS packages their install, but I've seen the above as the solution in a few places.

You should be able to determine the correct scripts by looking at the 'vars' scripts finding out which one points the KEY_DIR variable to the one you actually use (e.g. /etc/openvpn/keys, or /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys, or /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys)

Within the `vars' script verify the following 'variables' will have meaningful evaluations.

> KEY_CONFIG - should end up pointing to a valid file (hopefully a proper openssl.cnf file)

For example, I 'hardwire' mine to be 'export KEY_CONFIG=/etc/openvpn/openssl.cnf'

> KEY_DIR - this should point to you keys directory (possibly: /etc/openvpn/keys

another example, 'export KEY_DIR="/etc/openvpn/keys"'

Once that's working your next steps will be to

```
 $ sudo su
 # cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0
 # . ./vars
 # ./build-key new-client-name
```

The warning message will always come up after running . ./vars

Answer (score 0):

Check your permissions to the requires easy-rsa folders and /etc/ssl... In my case I had to run this as root:
sudo su
Not ideal, and be sure to 'exit' when finished to close the root terminal.